# Can't insert the following XML node VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, append, child-nodes

I want to append the following XML file to Include an additional `<ID>Sam</ID>`:

```
<INDEX>
  <ID>Billy</ID>
</INDEX>
```

However I cant seem to get it to work what I have tried is the following code.

```
Dim NEWNAME as string="SAM"
Dim xmlIndex As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlIndex.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\SYSTEM\MY_INDEX.xml")

With 
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/INDEX").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
.WriteStartElement("ID", NEWNAME)                                                                  
.WriteEndElement()
.Close()

xmlIndex.Save(Application.StartupPath & "\SYSTEM\MY_INDEX.xml")

End With
```

Also note for the convenience of this question I have declared `NEWNAME` as equalling `SAM`, but this could equally be a `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: What is it about your current code that doesn't work?  Does it get fail to compile, or throw an exception, or does it run fine but have no affect on the file?

Comment: it runs fine but no effect on the file

Comment: Well, you must have a bug in your code somewhere, then.  The code your posted in your question doesn't even compile, so it's impossible for us to tell why your code isn't working.  For instance, the syntax of the `With` block in your example is invalid and `xmlDoc` is never declared.  I suspect that the problem may lie in the fact that you are editing `xmlDoc` but then saving `xmlIndex`, but then again, maybe that's just another typo in your example...

Comment: Scratch that--the With block is valid.  But `Application` and `xmlDoc` don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I ususaly use something like this to write a new Node.

```
Dim NEWNAME As String = "SAM"
Dim xmlIndex As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlIndex.Load("C:\Test.xml")

Dim root As XmlNode = xmlIndex.DocumentElement
Dim elem As XmlElement = xmlIndex.CreateElement("ID")
elem.InnerText = NEWNAME
root.AppendChild(elem)

xmlIndex.Save("C:\Test.xml")
```